# ZipArchive comment

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I want to delete comment from some old zip-file. Can't find any "Comment" property in the [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). Any solution exists apart from "extracting all files and adding them into a new zip-file"?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the possibility to us another library, I recommend DotNetZipLib (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) It's very easy to use and you also can edit the comment.

```
  var file = @"C:\sample.zip";
  using (var zip = new ZipFile(file))
  {
    foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
    {
      entry.Comment = string.empty;
    }
    zip.Save();
  }
```

Comment: I was using SharpZipLib (also supplied as dll), thanks. Wanted something without dll and voila - .net 4.5 has it. But not as good, as it could be ><.